# Why Fibonacci numbers formula while loop return undefined at the last number?

Tags: javascript, while-loop, undefined, fibonacci

Why the last number of my Fibonacci number return undefined?

```
function sumFibs(num) {
var a = 1, b = 0, temp;

while (num >= 0){
temp = a;
a = a + b;
b = temp;
num--;
console.log(b);
};
}

console.log(sumFibs(4));//1,1,2,3,5,undefined
```

Comment: Add a language tag

Comment: Your function is not returning a value, and `console.log(sumFibs(4));` will output `undefined` because of it. The first 5 numbers are all from inside the loop.

Comment: Change `console.log(sumFibs(4));` to `sumFibs(4)` and it gets rid of the `undefined` for the reason @LasseV.Karlsen mentioned ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(sumFibs(4)); // executes `sumFibs`, but logs `undefined`.
```

This logs the return value of the `sumFibs` function.  Notice the function does not return a value, and therefore the return value is `undefined`.

Inside the `sumFibs` function, each number is output individually with `console.log(b)`.  As the `sumFibs` function executes, the numbers will be output individually.  Once the function completes and the return value of `undefined` is passed to `console.log`, it will conclude by logging `undefined` once at the end.

#### To fix this

Change:

```
console.log(sumFibs(4));
```

...to just:

```
sumFibs(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't added return statement in function call:
It should be like this -

```
function sumFibs(num) {
var a = 1, b = 0, temp;

while (num >= 0){
temp = a;
a = a + b;
b = temp;
num--;
console.log(b);
};
return b;
}

console.log(sumFibs(4));//1,1,2,3,5,5
```

If you remove console from while loop then you will get output as 5

```
function sumFibs(num) {
    var a = 1, b = 0, temp;
    
    while (num >= 0){
    temp = a;
    a = a + b;
    b = temp;
    num--;
    };
    return b;
    }
    
    console.log(sumFibs(4));//5
```